# Matching number with predifined patterns

Tags: php, mysql, regex, search

I have a problem that I have been thinking about for some time but failed to find the best solution.

The application is for a company that sells special phone numbers for different prices depending on the pattern of the number.

So the user has a stock of numbers. And defines patters using a some convention. For example:

- (ABCDEFG) represents a number with sequence such as (1234567, or
  2345678, etc...).
- (ZYX-ZYXW) represents a number such as (654-6543).

When customer picks up a number, the number should be matched against the patter it matches, and when a pattern is matched, the number is charged with the price of the matched pattern.

My thoughts are focused on three possible solutions:

1. I tried to think of regular expressions. But not sure if it can
   work.
2. Another solution would be looping over each possibility
   for each patter and matching it against the purchased number. But I
   am sure this is going to be too expensive performance wise.
3. Finally I thought to save all possible numbers when user adds a
   pattern so that when a clients wants to buy a new number, the
   application doesn't search patter but search actual numbers. This
   way the performance bottle neck would be when user adds a pattern
   (which is much less frequent than a client picking a number).

Do you guys have any advice regarding which approach should I use? Any hint is much appreciated.

**Edit:**

I'm very happy for the replies I received. They are all enlightening, however non so far can solve my problem. The real world scenario will the have the following condition:

- Some patters will follow some kind of digits order (sequential or non-sequential), such as: ABCDEFG=1234567, or ACEGECA=2468642.
- Some patters will be based on repetition of numbers, such as: xyxyxyx=1919191, or xyxzxyx=2829282. I guess in a way we can include this condition to the one above.
- Some patterns will have hard-coded digit, like ABC0ABC, or 123xyxy
- There is no limit to pattern possibilities.

So far all proposed methods have a limitation in their own ways. I am still think of it, so please if you come up with any helpful hit, share it with me!

Comment: Regexes would do just fine. For instance `ZYX-ZYXW` can be matched with `^(\d)(\d)(\d)-\1\2\3\d$` or `^(\d)((?!\1)\d)((?!\1|\2)\d)-\1\2\3(?!\1|\2|\3)\d$` if you want to make sure that X, Y, Z and W are all different numbers.

Comment: What about more complex patterns, such as (ACEGECA) like (2468642). The thing is I don't know what kind of patterns are going to be. If I chose the regex approach I need to develop a solution that converts the patters added by normal use to regex patter. Is that even possible?

Comment: Yup, that's possible. I'll write an answer. Do you actually require that A != C in your example above?

Comment: Actually there are two kinds of patters: one using squence that might or might not be repetitive (ABC-FGH). Another is using repetition of number (xyxyxyx, xxy*yxx).

Comment: I see questions along these lines come along once in a while (usually relating to DNA sequencing). In the past, the solution adopted often seems to involve application level code - as opposed to trying to solve the problem at the SQL, in case that's what you were thinking.

Answer (score 2):

An idea. [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jK5mQ7/1)

```
$number = '987-9876';
$suffix = <<<'EOD'
0123456789 ABCDEFG 10 ABCABCD 15
9876543210 GFEDCBA 8 DCBDCBA 13
EOD;

$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~
\A (?<number>(\d{3})-?(\d{4})) \R 
(?|
    \d*? # rectus
    (?|
        \2 \3 \d*
        [ ] (?<format> ABCDEFG ) [ ] (?<price>\d+)
      |
        (?=\3) \2 \d*
        (?> [ ] [A-Z]+ [ ] \d+)*? # other formats until the good one
        [ ] ( ABCABCD ) [ ] (\d+)
    )
  |
    .* \R \d*? # inversus
    (?|
        \2 \3 \d*
        [ ] ( GFEDCBA ) [ ] (\d+)
      |
        (?=\3) \2 \d*
        (?> [ ] [A-Z]+ [ ] \d+)*?
        [ ] ( DCBDCBA ) [ ] (\d+)
    )
)
~x
EOD;

if (preg_match($pattern, $number . PHP_EOL . $suffix, $m))
    echo 'number: ' . $m['number'] . PHP_EOL . 'format: ' . $m['format'] . PHP_EOL
       . 'price: ' . $m['price'];
```

**Other approach** *(probably the most performant)*

Special numbers are limited. You can produce and use a multidimensional array that contains all the special numbers, something like this:

```
$speNum = [
    'ABCDEFG' => [ '1234567', '2345678', '3456789' ],
    'GFEDCBA' => [ '9876543', '8765432', '7654321' ],
    'ABCABCD' => [ '1231234', '2342345' ... 
];

$prices = [ 'ABCDEFG' => 10, 'ABCABCD' => 15, 'GFEDCBA' => 8 ...];
```

And with a simple `foreach`, test if the number is in the array:

```
foreach ($speNum as $format => $nums) {
    if (in_array($number, $nums)) {
        echo 'number: ' . $number . PHP_EOL . 'format: ' . $format . PHP_EOL
           . 'price: ' . $prices[$format];
        break;
    }
}
```

Note: for this second approach (an why not for the first too), remove the hyphen before. The main advantage of this approach is that you can easily extend it to other kind of patterns. Note that you can do the same with your database.

Comment: That looks interesting, but I'm not very good with regex. Can you please explain what suffix is and what it does?

Comment: @Lamar; A regex engine is unable to count (it only deals with characters), so the only way for it to know that 2 is after 1 and 3 is after 2... is to write the sorted digits in the subject. In this way the regex engine is "able to count" (it can recognize if the digits in the number are in the suffix). After this "table", you can find formats and prices.

Comment: Please note that the real life patterns could be very diverse. It's almost impossible to list them all in design time. I need the users to write their own patterns (using A,B,C convention) in real time, and the application needs to convert it to the regular expression.

Comment: @Lamar: If you allow users to invent their own patterns (so not already known patterns), how do you determine the price? I think that patterns must be pre-determined (formats with associated prices) to make your system work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following strategy:
**pseudo code**

```
String getPattern(String pn,int n) 
    {
        
        int[] nums = new int[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            nums[i] = int.Parse(pn[i].ToString());
        Array.Sort(nums);
        String pat = pn;
        Char chr = 'A';
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            if (nums[i] != n)
            {
                pat = pat.Replace(nums[i].ToString(), chr.ToString());
                if ((i + 1) < 7)
                {
                    int shif = nums[i + 1] - nums[i];
                    chr = (Char)(Convert.ToUInt16(chr) + shif);
                }
            }

        }
        return pat;
    }
```

it worked for me with c# and it auto detect the pattern for entered number
also you can develop it to be more advanced (for example add zyx pattern detection)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is quite enlightening. Dare I ask you how to detect the other kind of patters which is repetition, for example (xyxyxyx, xyz*xyz) in which sequence is irrelevant.

Comment: Actually, now I'm thinking of it. we might patterns with hard coded digits, such as ABC0ABC. I don't think using your reverse approach might be able to cover these cases.

Comment: Thank for the help, as a matter of fact I meant any number, not only zero. The real problem is that I can not tell what the pattern might be. At any rate I am trying to code it myself. I will post the final result to the question when I finish. Any ideas or suggestions to share meanwhile are most appreciated :)